# How can the dates in a plot be written in another language different than english? (I am using matplotlib.dates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, locale

So I´m using matplotlib to plot some data and when I use matplotlib.dates, the dates are written in english, but I want the months to be written in spanish, so I tried to solve this by using:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es-ES.utf8')
```

However, I get the next Error:

```
Error: unsupported locale setting
```

And I don´t really know if using 'locale' actually works for the whole Jupyter enviroment. Does anybody has any suggestion?

Thank you! Best regards.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using MacOS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OS is Linux, replace the hyphen/dash character (`-`) by the underscore (`_`):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')
```

On Windows, I think you could use:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Spanish_Spain.1252')
```